# R find and replace values inside brackets

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want replace comma in string which is inside the square brackets not able to find solution how can I do using R anyone please help me

"{group_boundaries:[0,2620,2883], sample_boundaries:[0,40,80]}"

i wanted

"{group_boundaries:[0-2620-2883], sample_boundaries:[0-40-80]}"

Thank you

Comment: If your text string is called `str` you could do `stringr::str_replace_all(str, "\\[[^\\]]*\\]", function(x) stringr::str_replace_all(x, ",", "-"))`. Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @AllanCameron, I couldn't get any of the answers in the dupe-link to work with this data, perhaps I did it wrong? (Perhaps I should include my answer code below in that dupe-link ...)

Comment: @r2evans my code in the above comment works with the string that you have called `vec` - try `stringr::str_replace_all(vec, "\\[[^\\]]*\\]", function(x) stringr::str_replace_all(x, ",", "-"))`. I lifted that from MrFlick's answer in the linked dupe (albeit with minor tweaks). I didn't see your answer when I closed it, and wouldn't have bothered if I had. I don't mind if you think it should be reopened.

Comment: Okay, I must have mis-typed from the other, no worries. Actually, I think I clicked "Submit" (answer) a minute after you closed it, that is allowed in Stack's interface within 5 or 15 minutes or such of you closing it as a dupe. @AllanCameron

Answer (score 2):

Base R and its `gregexpr`:

```r
vec <- "{group_boundaries:[0,2620,2883], sample_boundaries:[0,40,80]}"
gre <- gregexpr("\\[[^]]+\\]", vec)
regmatches(vec, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] "[0,2620,2883]" "[0,40,80]"    
regmatches(vec, gre) |>
  lapply(gsub, pattern = ",", replacement = "-")
> 
# [[1]]
# [1] "[0-2620-2883]" "[0-40-80]"    
regmatches(vec, gre) <- regmatches(vec, gre) |>
  lapply(gsub, pattern = ",", replacement = "-")
vec
# [1] "{group_boundaries:[0-2620-2883], sample_boundaries:[0-40-80]}"
```

Regex:

```
"\\[[^]]+\\]"
 ^^^     ^^^  the literal brackets, escaped since they are used for regex classes
    ^^^^^     one or more of anything other than the close bracket
```